# Do Brits understand rhyming slang or are they sometimes puzzled by it too?

Tags: british-english, slang

Most people know that rhyming slang is a colorful addition to British English, where someone says something that is not the intended word but rhymes with it. For example,

> He was brown bread.

might be understood to mean

> He was dead.

When I watch British films I hear a lot of it, and some of it I get and some of it I don't. Is the expectation that some of it will be deliberately obscure, or is it just that my American ears aren't attuned to it? Are the instances that appear in movies in common usage, and so understood right away, or are they often created on the spot, verbal riffs that the listener has to think about and may or may not understand?

Comment: I'm curious why someone would down-vote this question.

Comment: They probably misread it and thought it was insulting British people, or some such, or perhaps they just really dislike rhyming slang.  I do hate vote downs without justification, should be compulsory.

Comment: I myself find the question interesting, and I was curious to know what the answer to the question was.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I say it *very* much depends what Britons you are talking about.  It is a dialectical style, found in a few places, but the most famous and that which tends to travel internationally is the East London, Cockney Rhyming Slang.

Now, most Londoners know a fair bit of it, growing up hearing it.  But it depends what area of London you were brought up in, and more importantly what class you were.  A lot of my friends use quite a bit of it, but not continuously like you see on films, it crops up as slang words, in the way that any other colloquialisms do.

Often, people do not know the etymology of the words they are using and do not know the rhyming part.  Commonly used words such as *barnet, boracic, china, cobblers, mickey, scarper* and *butchers* are used frequently, but few know the rhyming component for them, they just use the words.  *Cobblers* and *mickey* are more widely used than just London, not sure about the others.

---

As requested by Robusto, a brief set of rhyming expansions for the words I quoted above.

> *barnet* -> **barnet fair** -> *hair*
>
> Barnet Fair, was a regular horse trading fair held in the town of Barnet (my home town!), and well known by Londoners, as it was on the Great North Road, and was the major horse buying location for the capital.  Further back it was the largest cattle fair in the country too.<sup>[(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnet_Fair)</sup>
>
> *boracic* -> **boracic lint** -> *skint*
>
> Boracic lint was an often used dressing for wounds, lint soaked in boracic acid.  It rhymes with *skint* anyhow, which means pennyless, broke.  Note, we don't pronounce it boracic, it is pronounced as *brassic*, possibly due to people thinking that there is a link to the word *brass*, considering the financial connotations. (*brass* is a slang term for money, particularly coinage - reinforced by the proverb *"Where there's muck, there's brass."*)<sup>[(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boracic_lint)</sup>
>
> *china* -> **china plate** -> *mate*
>
> This one needs little explanation, we had china plates coming in to the capital by the boat load, it rhymes nicely with *mate*, which is the most popular word for *friend* in most London areas.  Though *bruv* gets used a lot these days in its place.
>
> *cobblers* -> **cobbler's awls** -> *balls*
>
> *Balls* being used in the slightly vulgar sense that *bollocks* is usually roped in for.  To say that something is untrue, or rubbish in some respect, mainly refuting something said by another.  The primary phrase I hear it used within is *"What a load of old cobblers!"*
>
> *mickey* -> **Mickey Bliss** -> *piss*
>
> Mickey Bliss was a bloke, supposedly from London, who no one knows anything about - he remains unidentified.  Except in infamy for being the source of this rhyming slang couplet, quite a recent edition to the pantheon, 1930s I believe.  Always used in the phrase *"taking the mickey"*, although *michael/mick* can be substituted, from *"taking the piss"*, which we [recently had a discussion about](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/what-does-the-british-idiom-taking-the-piss-mean/).  Note you can not use *mickey* for the act of urinating, the rhyming slang for that is *jimmy* (from Jimmy Riddle -> *piddle*).<sup>[(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taking_the_piss)</sup>
>
> *scarper* -> **Scapa Flow** -> *go*
>
> The etymology on this one is a little unclear, it is known as rhyming slang from [Scapa Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapa_Flow) (a very important natural harbour in the Orkney Islands) - but came additionally (and most likely originally) from the Italian immigrant population via their verb *scappare* which means *to escape*.  The current meaning is to make a quick get away, we [had a discussion on this word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/is-there-a-good-substitute-for-the-word-scarper-in-american-english) recently.  It was used heavily amongst certain groups, notably it was taken up in the Polari language in the old phrase *"scarper the letty"*, *letty* meaning bed/board/lodgings in Polari.
>
> *butchers* -> **butcher's hook** -> *look*
>
> We say, *"take/have a butchers"* to mean a quick look, synonymous with the word *gander* when used in that sense.

Hope that is of some interest to some of you, I do love etymology, particularly for obscure colloquialisms. :-)

Comment: Many people outside London will have heard it through TV shows (The Bill, EastEnders, etc.) even if they don't realise they are listening to rhyming slang.

Comment: @gpr: Aye, it travels well, even internationally as I mentioned.  Films like Lock, Stock expose it, but they take it way too far.

Comment: +1 for the excellent point that while the full rhyming slang isn’t terribly widely known/used, plenty of slang phrases derived from it are.

Comment: @PLL: Cheers.  The point is, that you're not supposed to use the rhymes, that annoys me a lot when people do.  Only the odd-ended word from the rhyming couplet; the rhyme lies unspoken and so, is forgotten.

Comment: @Orbling: I would love it if you would elaborate on the rhyming components for *barnet*, *borasic*, etc.

Comment: @Robusto: Right, etymology ahoy! (see above)

Comment: @Orbling: You are my hero! Thanks, and I owe you one (or more). I mean I owe you a buttered bun. I mean ...

Comment: @Robusto: Quite alright, you've given more than enough good answers here to warrant a favour.  It's interesting anyhow.

Comment: There are even new ones being coined. Listerine = anti-american. From,  Listerine = an anti-sceptic. sceptic-tank = yank. yank = american.

Comment: @mgb: There are always newly coined rhyming slang, some falls under *mockney*, ie. imitation cockney slang, rather than genuine; some could be considered modern usage.  [Slight spelling correction: *septic*, not *sceptic* - though I know many yanks who are anti-sceptic!]

Comment: Some quite nice modern ones are: Ayrton Senna = Tenner, Pete Tong = Wrong. As in, it's all gone a bit Pete Tong! Or, You owe me an Ayrton, my china!

Comment: Rhyming slang isn't restricted to London or even the British. Being born by the sound of Bow bells won't help you understand a Dubliner advising you to "lower your jimmy-joyce" or to "take the daniel-day".

Comment: @JonHanna: Not restricted to, no.  But it does help with those Dubliner phrases, as we are used to the concept, so automatically guess that direction.  I've not heard those phrases before, but I know what is meant by them.  Although I did need to know about the Luas to get it. ;-)

Comment: I suppose it's worth noting also, that since a lot of Cockney slang was originally from thieves' cant, then originally the whole point was that most people wouldn't understand it. (Like Polari, which you mention and which was also from East London, but from a different sub-culture).

Comment: @JonHanna: Well, my family of old were definitely in the East London, hmm, how should we put it, "not 100% in favour of the police", culture.  Not thieves at all, but they knew how to run from Metropolitan to City district or vice versa in a hurry. lol

Comment: What is 'skint'?

Comment: @Mitch *skint* means to be penniless, broke, without a farthing.

Comment: Good lord - I had no idea half of those were rhyming slang!

Comment: As with most dialects, rhyming slang varies from words every child would understand (and may not even know to be slang), to whimsy found only on tourist tea-towels. The examples in this answer are excellent: barnet, boracic, china, cobblers, mickey, scarper and butchers are all everyday words which you would expect someone in the South of England to understand without pause.

Answer (score 6):

There's a [Dick Francis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Francis) novel called *Driving Force* in which inability of the (London-based) hero to understand local rhyming slang hinders him from solving the mystery.  Presumably,  Francis's mostly British readership found that plausible.

Comment: As I remember, the rhyming slang involved wasn't standard, but was made up by the guy who used it (who was dead or missing—I can't remember which—so they couldn't ask him in person).

Answer (score 6):

Rhyming slang isn't made up by the speaker. It wouldn't really work as language if it was. Obviously it has to be made up by someone at some point, but the successful coinages spread and become part of the language. Often the second part of the phrase will become obscure (not many people know that "on my tod = on my own" refers to American jockey Tod Sloan, for example).

Modern attempts to introduce new rhyming slang terms tend to use the whole phrase — for example "It's all gone Pete Tong" (a radio DJ) for "it's all gone wrong", but can't really be considered successful until the second word is dropped. You wouldn't hear anyone say "it's all gone Pete".

In fact there seem to be very few if any genuine new rhyming slang terms emerging, probably because TV and white flight from the East End have changed the culture of that part of London. The most recent derivations I've seen date back to the 1930s.

Comment: This looks like a response to Jonathan Leffler's answer, rather than an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @Martha: it's an answer to the last piece of the question, which nobody else answered: " Are the instances that appear in movies in common usage, and so understood right away, or are they often created on the spot."

Answer (score 5):

I think many Britons do not understand rhyming slang; it was not part of my upbringing, though I was aware that rhyming slang existed.  The trouble is, the rhyming slang seems to mean whatever the speaker wants it to mean, without rhyme or reason that I can detect.  Some terms are relatively well known - 'pork pies' for 'lies'.  But most are obscure to the point of meaninglessness.

Rhyming slang was, by repute, beloved of Cockneys, who were people living in a specific area of London (towards the east and the docks, IIRC).  And there probably was a common corpus of rhyming slang, but many of the books I've read make a point that the rhyming slang seemed to be made up by the speaker, leaving it to the imagination of the hearer to understand what the speaker meant.  I believe it is a dying language form; I might be wrong about that, but the homogenization of language under the influence of first radio and later TV (and now films and the internet) makes it less and less likely to survive except as a deliberately obscure (and therefore affected but not effective) way of speaking.

Answer (score 5):

Most of what has been said previous is correct.

As stated by the previous geezers it depends on where abouts your from me old china. Most of the original of inhabitants of the East End (Bow Bells etc) have been forced to move out to Essex and to a lesser extent Kent (mainly Souf Lunduners moved down there innit).

However, you will still hear Cockney rhyming slang come out of the 'north and south' of Black Cab drivers (one of the last bastions for white Londeners to earn a crust).

As a Musher myself (thats an owner driver for you septic tanks - Yanks), I can speak an entire conversation in the smash and grab, on the hands free dog and bone with another cabbie and you wouldn't have the foggiest what I'm rabbitin on about.

I might say: whatcha Dave, hows the trouble? Be at mine at uncle Ben and will go for a ruby and a few pigs ears.

Translates: hello Dave, how's the wife (troubles and strife)? Be at mine at ten and we will go for a curry (Ruby Murray) and a few beers.

It's basically away of of having a natter or Frank and Pat (chat) to the exclusion of others, historically the Old Bill (police) or other authority figures. Though somtimes we use it to have a tin bath (laugh) at an outsiders expense. Innit.

Other words are used that are not necessarily rhyming slang, but metaphorical or allegorical in nature. For instance, if I was going for a hit and a miss (a piss/ to urinate) I might declare that I'm going to parliament - parliament being where all the Heads hang out (heads of government). Thus I'd be 'going to parliament' for a 'hit and a miss'. Going to the bog for a jimmy riddle etc. this kind of interchange between rhyming slang and metaphore basically leaves outsiders who speak the Queens (speaks English) dumbfounded, let alone Europeans etc.

In fact, I reckon Churchill would have ordered it to be used by resistance in WWII if the Gerrys had have landed and occupied.

Stand on me.

Comment: As a cabbie, you should know that there is no such thing as a South Londoner. City stops at the river! ;-)

Comment: Orbling: only after dark.

Comment: Read in the voice of Brick Top: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcG3JRIF05w

Answer (score 2):

Cockney rhyming slang originates in London and is spread across Britain by the London-based national media (most of it).

There are many other local dialects and slang words used in different areas of Britain which aren't universally understood.  These are less known across the whole country because of the London-based national media.

"I'll mash the tea"

"Well go t'foot of our stairs 'e 'a'n't washed 'is tabs for yonks"

"It's a bit black over Bill's mother's me old mucker.  I'll 'ave to get t'washing in"

"The postie left my parcel down the drang"

"Don't chuck it on floor, put it in the miskin"

The above examples contain words and phrases used in different parts of Britain but are rarely or never seen or heard in the media and aren't generally understood across the whole nation.

There are many phrases such as these.  However Cockney rhyming slang unfairly gets all the publicity.

Comment: I was once misunderstood to be being racist when I observed that it was black over Bill's mother's *in an area that wasn't the Black Country* (though I never worked out what they thought I meant). I'm still fairly sure that no-one in my Inverness office knows what I'm saying as I trill* tarrarabit* on my way out. But then, people in the Black Country didn't understand me when I was scunnered either.

Answer (score 1):

Rhyming slang is constantly evolving. Example a laugh used to be called a tin: as in you're having a tin (bath). You're having a laugh. Then some people used Turkish: as in you're having a Turkish (bath). You're having a laugh. Now most people use bubble: as in you're having a bubble (bath). You're having a laugh.

Note that when rhyming slang is being used correctly, you do not say the bit that rhymes. The whole point is to stop people who don't know the code, understanding what you are saying.