# Phrase for when someone leaves a group/place in an unusually quick manner

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, phrase-usage

For some reason I remember the phrase "that sounded runny" used when someone leaves a group/place in an unusually quick manner. But apparently that is incorrect. Can anyone help me with the correct phrase/usage? I remember the phrase being used in some TV show(s) or movie(s), but cannot put my finger on any specific instance.

Edit: I am looking for a permutation or correction in "that sounded runny" itself.

Comment: There is no well-established expression for your context based on any form of the word ***run***. The nearest I can think of is ***I gotta run***, said by the person who is leaving in a hurry (because he needs to be somewhere else *soon*).

Comment: You might find some inspiration [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/is-there-a-good-substitute-for-the-word-scarper-in-american-english/9658#9658).

Comment: the closest I can think of that might apply to the situation would be –only if someone were to describe the scene to you, not if you were witnessing yourself– : "the guy took off suddendly", you could answer "that sounds fishy"

Comment: "Back to the Future: let's make like a tree and get out of here" -Biff

Comment: Thank you all! Perhaps it's one of my 'memory artifacts'. :-)

Comment: "He sure did run, eh?"

Answer (score 1):

**skedaddle**

ske·dad·dle

> verb informal
>
> depart quickly or hurriedly; run away.

**Dip (out)**

> Urban Dictionary
>
> Verb
>
> to leave abruptly. To get the hell out of somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @ed86, but I'm looking for the permutation or correction in "that sounded runny" itself.

Answer (score 0):

"That was a quick exit"? I don't know that there's a specific phrase for this.

Answer (score 0):

When one is removed from the place on the instructions of some boss or other force it is said that they were *Spirited away*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps OP was thinking of **do a runner**.

> *do a runner* [fixed phrase; 'do' conjugable but 'runner' non-inflexionable] [British, informal]
>
> If someone does a runner, they leave a place in a hurry, for example
> in order to escape arrest or to avoid paying for something.
>
> - *At this point, the accountant did a runner–with all my bank statements, expenses and receipts.*

[[Collins Cobuild Advanced Learner’s Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/do-a-runner)] [amended]

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest,

***get (the hell) outta Dodge***

> *in.* To leave a place. (Refers to Dodge City, Kansas, and a cliché from Western entertainment adventures about this town.) *Things are looking bad here. It’s time to get out of Dodge*. [McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+out+of+Dodge)
>
> To leave or depart from a place, especially quickly or with marked urgency. A reference to Dodge City, Kansas, the clichéd setting of cowboy and western films from the early to mid-1900s. *It looks like things are getting pretty tense in here, let's get out of Dodge!* *With our creditors becoming increasingly aggressive, we decided to just get the hell out of Dodge and leave it all behind*. [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dodge)

***take to [one's] heels***

> To run away; flee. [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+to+heels)

***beat it***

> *Slang* To leave hurriedly [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+it)

***scram***

> *Slang* To leave a scene at once; go abruptly. [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scram)

Comment: Vamoose and escape rather fit the theme, too. (No idea where runny would fit.)